# android java How to override toString of ParseUser in nested class

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, overriding, extends

In Android, I am trying to override the toString() of the ParseUser for use in my listview, using

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.parse.FindCallback;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;
import com.parse.ParseUser;

import java.util.List;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class ExampleFragment extends Fragment {
    public ExampleFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_example, container, false);

        final ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.exampleListView);

        ParseQuery query = User.getQuery();

        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<User>() {
            public void done(List<User> objects, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    // The query was successful.
                    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<User>(rootView.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, objects));

                    for (User user : objects) {

                        Log.i("AppInfo", "Added " + user.toString());
                    }

                } else {
                    // Something went wrong.
                }
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

    public class User extends ParseUser {
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            Log.i("AppInfo", "Username: " + getUsername());
            return getUsername();
        }
    }
}
```

Seems simple enough. I had this nested in my fragment class and it crashed with this

java.lang.ClassCastException: com.parse.ParseUser cannot be cast to com.mycompany.myproject.ExampleFragment$User

but when I move it into its own subclass (where it gets its own entry in the explorer view in android studio), it works perfectly.

Is there a reason it does not work nested in my fragment class? Seems a bit unnecessary to create its own subclass just to override one function.

UPDATE: If I remove the for loop part it does not error out, but it still does not call my overridden toString() as the listview returns com.parse.ParseUser@etcetcetc.

Comment: MyFragment.User can be cast to ParseUser but the opposite don't. Every User is always an ParseUser... But not all ParseUser is a User... That's why the cast is failling... Probably, in your fragment, you defined a variable as "ParseUser". However, you should use it as "User"...

Comment: Please, share the code line where you define User/ParseUser object

Comment: Post relevant classes mate. Post the code where you're actually getting that error. I am certain you're mistaken, it shouldn't be like this

Comment: Thanks. Have updated with full code example. Basically all I've done is replaced where ParseUser used to be with User in the CreateView, and added the class bit to override toString().

Comment: I have a suspicion that it might be the combination of it being a nested class as well as being nested in a fragment class. Maybe something to do with lifecycles or something

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have do these 2 things

1.register class before  Parse.initialize

```
ParseObject.registerSubclass(User.class);
```

2.use annotation to specified the class mapping to waht Class

```
@ParseClassName("_User")
public class User extends ParseUser {
    ...
}
```

here is the reference.
https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#objects-subclassing-parseobject

Comment: Thanks. I've just tried that using
    ParseUser.registerSubclass(ExampleFragment.User.class);
as my initialize is in another part. Am now getting an error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot register a type that does not implement the default constructor!

Comment: have you add this annotation? @ParseClassName("_User")

Comment: Hi Yes I added @ParseClassName("_User") and still same issue

Comment: Maybe try to move your User class to User.java avoid nested class.

Comment: inside the class annotated with @ParseClassName you must add a default constructor with no argument

meaning :
    public  User(){}